# Detect edit event on a textField view in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a cell array not in a cell collection or UItable. How do I detect an edit event on one of the cells?

Comment: use `UITextFieldDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, set tags to your all textfields. so that you can recognise current textfield.

```
[textfield setTag:101];
```

Set delegate for each textfield.

```
[textfield setDelegate:self];
```

and at last use UITextField delegate textFieldDidBeginEditing for detecting "edit"

```
    - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
            if(textField.tag == 101){
               //do something
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set textfield Delegate "`UITextFieldDelegate`" for access the textfield methods.
And impliment the "`textFieldDidBeginEditing`" methods for detect an edit even in textfield.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     if ([textField isEqual:"Your TextField Outlet name"])
         //Do Something you code
         //Return Value (true or false)
}
```

For Example:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
         if ([textField isEqual:txtContactNo])
             //Do Something you code
             //Return Value (true or false)

        return YES;
    }
```